# Quickest way to set properties on an object?

Tags: .net

Assume you have a business object with a lot of properties. What is the easiest and best way to set the properties without the use of an ORM tool?

This implies setting properties from a data reader object, such as

```
client.Name = (string)reader["Name"];
```

What about the case where the object contains other complex objects?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serialization and/or Reflection is an option.

Comment: Reflection poses a problem where the column name does not match the objects corresponding property name.

Comment: Unless you specify a mapping between column names and property names, you can't achieve what you want. Specifying such a mapping brings you to building a custom ORM, or using an existing one.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could use reflection to generate the assignation code.

Answer (score 0):

You ask for three different things:

- quickest
- easiest
- best

they are not the same! The *quickest* (at execution) would be compiled code; i.e. you write regular C# to set the properties correctly. Easier than this is using reflection - but that is slow. You'd also need some mechanism for mapping child properties... (and also mapping regular properties if there isn't a 1:1 correspondance between the reader). This is perhaps best solved with custom attributes on members (properties/fields).

As a compromise on speed (over reflection), you can use Delegate.CreateDelegate to get at the property setters - but that is a lot of work. Perhaps another option is [HyperDescriptor](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/HyperPropertyDescriptor.aspx); this allows reflection-like access, but is vastly faster.

Best? Probably to use existing code - i.e. an ORM tool; less to write and debug.

Comment: well, I guess by quickest, he meant quickest to write, not quickest to execute.